# can't delete row where content start by 0. android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want delete row from click button, when i delete number "1231312", row has been deleted but if delete number "08982312" row not delete. every number start by 0, row can't delete not force close but not delete.
here my list code:

BlackListProvider.java

> public class BlackListProvider extends ContentProvider {
>       public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "skripsi.ebranda.provider.blacklist";

```
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"
        + PROVIDER_NAME + "/blacklist");

public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String Number = "number";

static final int BLACKLIST = 1;
static final int BLACKLIST_ID = 2;

static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "blacklist", BLACKLIST);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "blacklist/#", BLACKLIST_ID);
}

// ---for database use---
static SQLiteDatabase blacklistDB;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BlackList";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "blacklist";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + " number text not null);";

public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("Content provider database",
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    // ---get all books---
    case BLACKLIST:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.com.blacklist ";
        // ---get a particular book---
    case BLACKLIST_ID:
        return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.blacklist ";
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    Context context = getContext();
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    blacklistDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return (blacklistDB == null) ? false : true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    SQLiteQueryBuilder sqlBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    sqlBuilder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLE);

    if (uriMatcher.match(uri) == BLACKLIST_ID)
        // ---if getting a particular book---
        sqlBuilder.appendWhere(_ID + " = " + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));

    if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "")
        sortOrder = _ID;

    Cursor c = sqlBuilder.query(blacklistDB, projection, selection,
            selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

    // ---register to watch a content URI for changes---
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    // ---add a new book---
    long rowID = blacklistDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, "", values);

    // ---if added successfully---
    if (rowID > 0) {
        Uri _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(_uri, null);
        return _uri;
    }
    throw new SQLException("Failed to insert row into " + uri);
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri arg0, String arg1, String[] arg2) {
    // arg0 = uri
    // arg1 = selection
    // arg2 = selectionArgs
    int count = 0;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(arg0)) {
    case BLACKLIST:
        count = blacklistDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, arg1, arg2);
        break;
    case BLACKLIST_ID:
        String id = arg0.getPathSegments().get(1);
        count = blacklistDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, _ID + " = " + id
                + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(arg1) ? " AND (" + arg1 + ')' : ""),
                arg2);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + arg0);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(arg0, null);
    return count;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    int count = 0;
    switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case BLACKLIST:
        count = blacklistDB.update(DATABASE_TABLE, values, selection,
                selectionArgs);
        break;
    case BLACKLIST_ID:
        count = blacklistDB.update(
                DATABASE_TABLE,
                values,
                _ID
                        + " = "
                        + uri.getPathSegments().get(1)
                        + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND ("
                                + selection + ')' : ""), selectionArgs);
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}
```

BlackList.java

> public class BlackList extends ListActivity {

```
private ArrayList<String> numberList;
private Cursor cursor = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListAdapter adapter = createBlackListAdapter();
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the textview text
            // CharSequence content = ((TextView)view).getText();
            TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tulisan);
            String address = t1.getText().toString();
            popUp(address);
        }
    });

}
public void popUp(String address) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("address", address);
    bundle.putString("deletebutton", "Delete");
    bundle.putString("closebutton", "Close");

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
            ListNumberBlack.class);
    newIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivityForResult(newIntent, 0);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.addnumbermenu){
        startActivity(new Intent(BlackList.this,AddBlackList.class));
        return (true);
            }
    return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}



protected ListAdapter createBlackListAdapter() {
    try {
        numberList = new ArrayList<String>();

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                                BlackListProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                null,
                                null, 
                                null,
                                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String number = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("number"));

                numberList.add(number);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
    }
    return new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.list_item,numberList);

}
```

}

ListNumberBlack

> public class ListNumberBlack extends Activity {

```
private String address;
protected static final String ID_EXTRA = "skripsi.ebranda.nomorespam._ID";
long id;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_number);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    address = bundle.getString("address");
    //id = bundle.getInt(ID_EXTRA);
    //String X = String.valueOf(id);
    final String s = String.valueOf(address);
    Toast.makeText(ListNumberBlack.this,
            s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    // set text
    TextView txtContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ListNumber);
    txtContent.setText(address);
    // --set button
    // cancel button
    String name = txtContent.getText().toString();

    Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                // hapus pesan
        Dialog.showConfirmation(ListNumberBlack.this,
                R.string.hapus2,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        BlackListProvider.blacklistDB.delete(BlackListProvider.DATABASE_TABLE, BlackListProvider.Number
                                + "=" + s, null);
                                finish();
                                Toast.makeText(ListNumberBlack.this,
                                        "Nomor Terhapus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
            }

        });
```

}       });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of an exact answer, but I got a couple of ideas you may want to try:

1- why do you have `final String s = String.valueOf(address);` ? why not just `final String s = address;`?

2- try adding single quotation mark to the `String s`, like this:

```
BlackListProvider.blacklistDB.delete(BlackListProvider.DATABASE_TABLE, 
        BlackListProvider.Number + "='" + s +"'", null);
```

Let me know if any of that helps.